# Python. Error al cargar imagen con el módulo Pillow

Tags: python

Básicamente acabo de instalar pillow y la instalación fue exitosa. Pero al ejecutar este código no pasa absolutamente nada, ni errores ni la imagen y la verdad no sé porque pasa.

```
from PIL import Image

im = Image.open("lion.png")

im.show()
```

Tengo que reiniciar el pc luego de instalar un módulo? Por cierto uso windows 7 y tengo python 3.8. Si esto no se puede solucionar hay algún módulo alternativo?

Comment: la imagen lion.png está a la misma altura que el archivo donde tienes este código?

Answer (score 0):

Hola he intentado hacer lo mismo que tu pero no logré mostrar la imágen. La solución para este problema con PIL es usar "tkinter" para usar un componente "label" del mismo y ahi poner la imagen y mostrarla.

Ejemplo:

```
#Importar librerias necesarias
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

window = tk.Tk()
#establecer tamaño de ventana (opcional)
#window.geometry("500x500")    
ruta_imagen = "ejemplo.jpg"
#Pasar la imagen al formato ImageTk
img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(ruta_imagen))
#poner la imagen en un label de tkinter
lbl = tk.Label(window, image = img).pack()
#mostrar
window.mainloop()
```

Probado en python 3.6

(*) Tkinter en python 2.x se importa como

```
import Tkinter as tk
```

En python 3 se importa como en el ejemplo.

Solo cambia la T mayúscula a minúscula.